# How to eliminate duplicate records in this query

Tags: mysql

I have got historical data for stock symbols an this is my data

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `historical_data` (
  `symbol_name` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `current_day` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `open_val` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `high_val` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `low_val` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `close_val` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_val` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prevclose_val` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `symbol_name` (`symbol_name`,`current_day`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `historical_data` (`symbol_name`, `current_day`, `open_val`, `high_val`, `low_val`, `close_val`, `last_val`, `prevclose_val`) VALUES
    ('ZYDUSWELL', '13-DEC-2015', '814.75', '816.75', '784.25', '811.7', '811.50', '811.50'),
    ('ZYLOG', '13-DEC-2015', '2.9', '2.95', '2.85', '2.95', '2.95', '2.19'),
    ('ZYDUSWELL', '17-DEC-2015', '815.75', '815.75', '785.25', '810.7', '813.50', '813.50'),
    ('ZYLOG', '17-DEC-2015', '2.9', '2.95', '2.85', '2.95', '2.95', '2.19');
```

And this is how i am fetching Top Looser's for 1 Week

```
SELECT *  FROM (SELECT distinct symbol_name , ROUND((prevclose_val-close_val),2) AS losers, STR_TO_DATE(current_day, '%d-%M-%Y'), 'weekly' AS `type` 
        FROM historical_data 
        WHERE date_format( STR_TO_DATE(current_day, '%d-%M-%Y'), '%Y%m%d')  >= date_format(date_sub(now(), interval 7 day), '%Y%m%d')
        ORDER BY losers ASC 
      ) AS sub_weekly;
```

and the result i am seeing is that duplicate Symbols in the result

Could you please tell me how can i eliminate duplicate records

and this is my sqlfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9c28/6

**Edited Part**

Actual Result Which was working fine before using GROUP BY

[image]

Now After Using Group By the result is

[image]

Comment: `current_day varchar(50)` Please don't store date as string, problems with conversions/comparing and so on.

Comment: @lad2025 i will follow this from future .

Comment: What are the expected results?

Comment: I am getting symbol duplicated from the results

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9c28/6

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to see distinct symbol so you could just do GROUP BY as follows:

```
 SELECT *  FROM 
(SELECT distinct symbol_name , 
 ROUND((prevclose_val-close_val),2) AS losers, 
 STR_TO_DATE(current_day, '%d-%M-%Y'), 'weekly' AS `type` 
        FROM historical_data 
        WHERE date_format( STR_TO_DATE(current_day, '%d-%M-%Y'), '%Y%m%d')  >= date_format(date_sub(now(), interval 7 day), '%Y%m%d')
        GROUP BY symbol_name 
        ORDER BY losers ASC 
) AS sub_weekly;
```

Result Set:

```
symbol_name losers  STR_TO_DATE(current_day, '%d-%M-%Y')    type
ZYLOG   -0.76   December, 13 2015 00:00:00  weekly
ZYDUSWELL   -0.2    December, 13 2015 00:00:00  weekly
```

Comment: just a minute i am working on that , i will update .

Comment: Could you please see the edited part in my question after using the GROUP BY symbol_name  the reesults are wrong .

Comment: I've looked into data set interestingly you have different data result especially check the dates they are different so please make sure that where conditions is same for both queries with and without group by.